# $H$ separable Hilbert space, then murray-von neumann equiv. projections have the same dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, k-theory

Let $H$ be a separable, infinite dimensional Hilbert space.  I wish to show that for projections $p,q\in B(H)$, then $p\sim q$ if and only if $dim(pH)=dim(qH)$. Note that $p\sim q$ means that there exists an element $v\in B(H)$ such that $p=v^*v$ and $q=vv^*$.

Now I don't know how to do this, but it is because I haven't figured out how to generalized my idea when $H=\mathbb{C^n}$.  If this is the case, then a projection over $\mathbb{C^n}$ is given by a matrix and this matrix will be diagonalizable.  Since the only eigenvalues of $p$ are $0$ or $1$, then the trace of $p$ will precisely be the number of times $1$ appears on the diagonal, which is the same as its dimension.  Hence if $p\sim q$, then they have the same trace so they have the same dimension.  The other direction I am not sure.

The problem I encounter is that when $H$ is infinite dimensional, separable, then these "matrices" that represent $p$ are "infinite matrices", but this isn't rigorous.  Could someone please help me with a hint or solution?

Edit:  With the comment from Mike F., I have shown that $v:pH\to qH$ is a hilbert space isomorphism, which implies dim(p)=dim(q).

Conversely, supposing that dim(p)=dim(q), take $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ as ONB for pH and $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ as ONB for qH.

We can define a map $v$ from the span of $\{e_i\}$ via $\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i e_i\mapsto \sum_{i\in  I}\lambda_i f_i$. whenever the element in the span is norm convergent.  Since $v$ is linear, continuous and the span of $\{e_i\}$ is dense in pH, $v$ should extend to a unique, continuous operator from $v:pH\to qH$.

Here is where I get confused.  I know that I need to extend $v$ again as an operator in $B(H)$ such that $v^*v=p$ and $vv^*=q$, but I am not sure how to do this. I also need $v$ to be an isometry from $pH$ and $qH$, i.e. for all $x,y\in pH$, $<x,y>=<vx,vy>$.  My issue with showing that claim in particular is the somewhat vague description of an adjoint operator and the fact that I am not sure how $v$ and $v^*$ "look like" on elements that aren't in the span of their respective ONB that I listed earlier.

Comment: The subspaces $pH$ and $qH$ are closed, so can be thought of as Hilbert spaces in their own right. To show they have the same (Hilbert space) dimension, you can exhibit a Hilbert space isomorphism  $pH \to qH$. Try to use the element $v$ to do this.

Comment: This works great.  I am now having a bit of difficulty with the reverse direction.

Comment: If $pH$ and $qH$ have the same dimension as Hilbert spaces, then they are isomorphic as Hilbert spaces. That is, there is an isometry $w$ mapping $pH$ onto $qH$. There is a canonical way to think of $w$ as a map $v: H \to H$. Just define $vx = wx$ when $x \in pH$ and $vx =0$ when $x$ is orthogonal to $pH$. Such a map $v$ is called a "partial isometry", since the important thing is that it gives an isometry between two subspaces of $H$, and we have made it into a map $H \to H$ rather artificially. You can check that this $v$ implements a Murray-von Neumann equivalence between $p$ and $q$.